# Asp.net MVC Razor more than one form on a page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, razor

Yo

I have a registration page on my site - at the top of the page is a login form for existing users. In the main area there is the registration form.

The login are is a partial view with `@model ViewModels.LoginViewModel`
The registration are is also a partial with `@model ViewModels.RegViewModel`

The main page which houses these partials is a view with `@model ViewModels.RegPageViewModel`

This viewmodel looks like:

```
public class RegViewModel
{
    public RegisterVm RegisterVm { get; set; }
    public LoginVm LoginVm { get; set; }
}
```

When I submit the registration part of the page (it's action is register/capture - the receiving action expects a RegisterVm) to it's controller it complains about being passed the wrong viewmodel

What's the deal with subviews and their viewmodel? Is there a standard approach to dealing with this?

Should I have one submit URL for this page which figures out if it's a login request or a register request and then handles the post accordingly? That seems messy to me though...

http://monobin.com/__d33cf45a4 - RegisterVm.cs (LoginVm.cs is pretty much the same as this)

http://monobin.com/__m69132f76 - RegPageVm.cs

Register.cshtml:

```
@model xxxx.ViewModels.RegPageVm
@{
    View.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_BareBones.cshtml";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Public/Css/signup.css")" type="text/css" />
<div id="sign-up-container">
    <div id="sign-up-box">
        <div id="sign-up-box-left">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Public/Images/Signup_176x81.png")" />
        </div>
        <div id="sign-up-box-right">
           @Html.Partial("_Register")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
```

_Register.cshtml:

```
@model xxxx.ViewModels.RegisterVm

@using (Html.BeginForm("Capture", "Register", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="sign-up-box-inner">
        <tr>
            <td class="label-area">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)
            </td>
            <td class="field-area">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "login-input", title = "Enter Name" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label-area">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password)
            </td>
            <td class="field-area">
                @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "login-input", title = "Enter Name" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label-area">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.UserName)
            </td>
            <td class="field-area">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName, new { @class = "login-input", title = "Enter Name" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="image" src="../../Public/Images/Submit_150x47.png" class="submit-button" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
```

And finally RegisterController.cs:

```
public class RegisterController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           return View();
        }

        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Capture(RegisterVm registerVm)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("index", new RegPageVm()
                {
                    LoginVm = new LoginVm(),
                    RegisterVm = registerVm
                });
            }

            return RedirectToAction("index", "Event");
        }
    }
```

w://

Comment: Can we see some of the code from the View?

Comment: shouldn't it be @Html.Partial("_Register", Model.RegisterVm) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that the form elements (like the textbox etc) should have the same id as the RegisterVM and LoginVM properties. Your theory is right but I think you might be making a mistake in the naming convention of MVC.

If you can share your view code + the VM classes, then we'll be able to help better.

**EDIT:**

Looking at your code I think you should be passing the view model to your partial view. Like for example the following line believe should be like this  >

`@Html.Partial("_Register", Model.RegisterVm)`

Comment: i'm using Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.PropertyName) so that should take care of that no?

Comment: That should work. Again can we see your code; the view, one of the partial views and its corresponding viewmodel. There might be some issue in passing the model to the partial view.

Answer (score -1):

According to your answer to nEEbz:

You are using:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.LoginVM.Email) // i guess
```

this would turn into `<input name="LoginVM.Email" ...>`

Notice the `LoginVM.` part

Your login action probably looks like:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginVM model) { }
```

so it expect field names like `Email` and `Password`, not `LoginVM.Email` and `LoginVM.Password`.

So you could could use `Html.Textbox` instead (so that the field name doesn't get autocreated).

Comment: The sub views have @model ViewModels.LoginViewModel and @model ViewModels.RegViewModel accordingly so they don't use that notation - i'm assuming that mvc knows to match up the viewmodel hierarchy - or am i wrong? Do I need to call RenderPartial by specifying the part of the viewmodel to use somehow?

Comment: Did you check the HTML that was created? (view source)